# Showing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(xn)}{n}$ converges for $x \in (0,2 \pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

> How do you show that for $x \in (0,2 \pi)$ the following series converges?
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(xn)}{n}$$

Of course, this series doesn't converge absolutely. For $x= \pi$ you get the convergence with  the Leibniz criterion. For other $x$ in that interval the cosine is still often enough positive and negative evenly distributed that I expect the series to converge. How to formally prove that?

Comment: Have you heard of Abel transformation ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: Dirichlet's Test is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}=\Re \left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i nx}}{n}\right]$$

This then [simplifies](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28exp%28i%20x%20n%29%2Fn%2C%28n%2C1%2Cinfty%29%29) to

$$=\Re\left[-\ln(1-e^{ix})\right]$$

You could prove this using the Taylor Series for $\ln(1-x)$ but this is difficult in my mind as that series is normally defined for $|x|<1$ and thus requires more fines. To get the real part of this we have

$$1-e^{ix}=1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)=\sqrt{2-2 \cos (x)}e^{i\phi}$$

where $\phi=\arg(1-e^{ix})$. Then

$$\Re\left[-\ln(1-e^{ix})\right]=\Re\left[-\ln\left(\sqrt{2-2 \cos (x)}e^{i\phi}\right)\right]$$

$$=\Re\left[-i\phi-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2-2\cos(x))\right]=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2-2\cos(x))$$

This exists for all $x\neq 2\pi k$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

$$y(x)=\cos x +\frac {\cos 2x}2+\frac {\cos 3x}3 +\cdots +\frac{ \cos nx}{n}.$$

Take derivative of all term and sum up you get:

$$y'(x)=-(\sin x+ \sin 2x +\sin 3x +\cdots+ \sin nx)=-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2x\right) \sin\left(\frac n{2}x\right)}{\sin \frac x2}.$$

Now integrate and find the limit.

Comment: What is $n$ and $y$? Be a bit more specific. Is the last step obvious?

Comment: @Gary, I edited my answer.